# How can a make new list from a 2d list with specific conditions?

Tags: python, list, 2d

I need to tell you that I know very basic things about python (and programming generally), so I would like an explained answer if that is possible.
So I have an exercise where I have a kind of list like this:

```
data_list = [["John", "Physics", 5],["John", "Mathematics", 7],["John", "Ancient Greek", 8],["Maria", "Physics", 6],["Maria", "Programming", 10]]
```

and I want to create a new list that every row contains the name of the student, and the name of all the subjects that he/she has. It is gonna look like that:

```
 [[John,Physics,Mathematics,Ancient Greek],[Maria,Physics,Programming]]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I just want an explanation on how to do this. To be honest, i am so confused with 2d lists, that i am mostly looking around for similar exercises, or things that they have taught us, but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried to solve it with inner and outer list "logic" if i am saying it correctly, because this is what they've taught us to use in these cases, but it seems, i am not getting it right.

Comment: you can solve it using dictionary

Comment: but they want it as a list, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

using `Setdefault()`

```
d={}
for x,y,z in data_list:
    d.setdefault(x,[]).append(y)
print(d)
```

Using setdefault() and dictionary comprehension.

```
new_dict = {d.setdefault(x,[]).append(y) for x,y,z in data_list}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'John': ['Physics', 'Mathematics', 'Ancient Greek'], 'Maria': ['Physics', 'Programming']}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time ! The thing is they want it as a list